# Using Kendo popup Angular with anchor

Tags: kendo-ui, popup, popover, kendo-angular-ui

I am trying to use kendo-popup with the input anchor but it doesn't work for me properly.
I want from app.component.html to have:

```
  <div class="first-container flex-column">
    <!-- a lot of elements -->
  </div>
  <div class="second-container flex-column">
     <!-- a lot of elements -->
  </div>
  <kendo-popup [anchor]="anchor">
      <div class='content'>
          <!-- User-defined content -->
          Popup content.
      </div>
  </kendo-popup>
```

And the #anchor id can be deep inside one of the containers.

I want to create generic kendo-popup and it should open the popup each time near to other element (that has the anchor).

If I put #anchor inside an element in one of the containers it's not popup near that element, and it popup in a place that not related to this element.

How should I do it?

BTY, I tried first using ngbPopover of ngBootsrap but it requires to 'wrap' the html element that we want the popover on, this doesn't work for me because I want to put the popover/popup code in generic place that I will use for multiple elements.

Thanks!